# How to create treeview and treenode in .Net core console application

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, .net-core, console-application

I have an .Net core console application.it has to be run on Linux os.
I have to use treeview and treenode functionalities in my .Net console application.i used windows.forms namespace..
But visual studio giving publish
Error is " There is no runtime package for windows.forms"
How to handle this?

Comment: You can't use windows forms on Linux. It doesn't make much sense to do so in a console app anyway. Are you sure you are not supposed to simulate a tree in the console?

Comment: Hi,How can I create custom treeview and treenode classes? I need some of the property and methods from treeview and treenode... I don't require GUI related methods or properties...

Answer (score 0):

You might not need it anymore, but for anyone looking for a solution there is this package https://github.com/gui-cs/Terminal.Gui that allows to build rich CLI applications. They have an interactive tree component: https://gui-cs.github.io/Terminal.Gui/docs/treeview.html